# How can turn off page prefetching Next.js Link on hover?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my production, when we hover over whatever link in the application, the XHR request will send to the server. Therefore I need to prevent that option.

I used `prefetch={false}` it doesn't work. Any solution for this issue?

```
 <Link href={`${path}${card.post_details.slug}`} prefetch={false}> 
   Read More
 </Link>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`prefech={false}` disable prefetching in all scenarios but not on hover, as you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link):

> When prefetch is set to false, prefetching will still occur on hover.

In this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/24437#discussioncomment-3752350), one of the mainters says about a [pull request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/39866) he made about `prefech`:

> To be precise, only the new router for https://nextjs.org/blog/layouts-rfc will disable prefetching on hover. For the existing router, it is still relevant to do prefetching on hover as it is not a single pass to load code and data.

So if this is so important to you, maybe try migrating to Next 13, and use the `app` directory.

Answer (score 0):

am facing same issue i add
experimental: { optimisticClientCache: false, }
in next.config file.It works for me

Comment: Hi ! Can you please explain why / how does this config fixes the issue (maybe add a link to documentation) and let future users know why (in which case) they should use this solution rather to approved answer ?